# Generating table row by row after user input

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html-table

When the user enters the page, an HTML table with two rows is generated. First row is the table header, while the second row in its first cell has an input box, while the other cells are empty.

| barcode | product | amount | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `input box` |  |  |  |

After the user enters the barcode in the input box I need to:

1. update the other cells with the details of the product (stored into a MySQL database) based on the barcode inserted;
2. generate another row like the previous one.

So, after the first input the table should be like this:

| barcode | product | amount | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54573498759384 | trousers | 10 | 99 $ |
| `input box` |  |  |  |

and so on...

I read here and there and I came to conclusion that I probably need AJAX, but I never used it before so your help, just to start, in as simple as possible words, would be really appreciated.

I am using only PHP and Javascript. I never used JQuery.

Thanks in advance.

At the moment I haven't found a way.

Comment: do show us the code you've come up with so far

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this; better to keep learning plain Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your ajax call to get data from your backend in the onBarcodeChange function

```js
function onBarcodeChange(id) {
  // ... cal your backend/SQL to get data
  const mockData = {
    product: `Product ${id}`,
    amount: getRandomInt(100),
    price: getRandomInt(10)
  }

  const {
    product,
    amount,
    price
  } = mockData
  
  document.getElementById(`product${id}`).innerText = product
  document.getElementById(`amount${id}`).innerText = amount
  document.getElementById(`price${id}`).innerText = price

  addTableRow(id + 1)
}

function addTableRow(id) {

  const barcodeInput = document.createElement('input')
  barcodeInput.placeholder = "Enter barcode"
  barcodeInput.onchange = () => onBarcodeChange(id)

  // create 4 cells
  const cellNames = ['barcode', 'product', 'amount', 'price']
  const cells = cellNames.map(name => {
    const cell = document.createElement('td')
    cell.id = `${name}${id}`
    return cell
  })

  // add input to the 1st cell
  cells[0].appendChild(barcodeInput)

  const row = document.createElement('tr')
  cells.forEach(cell => row.appendChild(cell))

  const table = document.getElementById('products')
  table.appendChild(row)

  barcodeInput.focus()
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
  const min = 1
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table id='products'>
  <tr>
    <th>barcode</th>
    <th>product</th>
    <th>amount</th>
    <th>price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='barcode1'>
      <input placeholder="Enter barcode" onchange="onBarcodeChange(1)">
    </td>
    <td id="product1"></td>
    <td id="amount1"></td>
    <td id="price1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```